# ASP.NET Core issues with DB2 queries in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, db2, .net-core

I'm working on a web app in ASP.Net Core v1.0 in VS2015. The premise of this application is simply to retrieve information from our DB2 database and display it for our dispatchers to use. The issue I'm running into is while on my development PC the application runs fine in IIS Express but once deployed I get the following error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero.

So I know that my query is coming back with no results, I have tried changing settings in IIS but I can't seem to get this to work. The results are retrieved and displayed correctly when debugging on my PC. Also this is the code behind of the retrieving controller:

```
public ViewResult EvvCityFull()
    {

        DB2Command myDB2Command = null;
        string myDb2ConnectionString = "Server=Server;Database=DB;UID=User;PWD=Pass;";
        DB2Connection myDb2Connection = new DB2Connection(myDb2ConnectionString);
        myDb2Connection.Open();
        myDB2Command = myDb2Connection.CreateCommand();
        myDB2Command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT FINAL_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID, FINAL_DRIVERS.NAME, FINAL_DRIVERS.STATUS, FINAL_DRIVERS.REMAINING_HOURS, FINAL_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_LOC, FINAL_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_DATE FROM " +
                                   "(" +
                                   "SELECT BASE_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID, BASE_DRIVERS.NAME, BASE_DRIVERS.STATUS, BASE_DRIVERS.REMAINING_HOURS, BASE_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_LOC, BASE_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_DATE, DATA AS EMPLOYMENT " +
                                   "FROM " +
                                   "(" +
                                   "SELECT BOARD_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID, BOARD_DRIVERS.NAME, BOARD_DRIVERS.STATUS, BOARD_DRIVERS.REMAINING_HOURS, BOARD_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_LOC, BOARD_DRIVERS.LAST_SAT_DATE, DATA AS CITY " +
                                   "FROM " +
                                   "(" +
                                   "SELECT DRIVER_ID, NAME, STATUS, REMAINING_HOURS, LAST_SAT_LOC, LAST_SAT_DATE, DATA AS BOARD FROM TMWIN.DRIVER, TMWIN.CUSTOM_DATA " +
                                   "WHERE DRIVER_ID = SRC_TABLE_KEY " +
                                   "AND ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' " +
                                   "AND CUSTDEF_ID = 6 " +
                                   "AND DATA IN('CITY') " +
                                   "AND REMAINING_HOURS IS NOT NULL " +
                                   "AND STATUS IS NOT NULL " +
                                   ") BOARD_DRIVERS, " +
                                   "TMWIN.CUSTOM_DATA " +
                                   "WHERE BOARD_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID = SRC_TABLE_KEY " +
                                   "AND CUSTDEF_ID = 7 " +
                                   "AND DATA IN('EVANSVILLE') " +
                                   ") BASE_DRIVERS, " +
                                   "TMWIN.CUSTOM_DATA " +
                                   "WHERE BASE_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID = SRC_TABLE_KEY " +
                                   "AND CUSTDEF_ID = 9 " +
                                   "AND DATA IN('FULL-TIME') " +
                                   ") FINAL_DRIVERS LEFT JOIN TMWIN.CUSTOM_DATA " +
                                   "ON FINAL_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID = SRC_TABLE_KEY ORDER BY FINAL_DRIVERS.DRIVER_ID ASC";
        DB2DataReader myDb2DataReader = null;
        List<Driver> result = new List<Driver>();

        using (myDb2DataReader = myDB2Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (myDb2DataReader.Read())
            {

                Driver driver = new Driver();
                driver.DRIVER_ID = myDb2DataReader["DRIVER_ID"].ToString();
                driver.NAME = myDb2DataReader["NAME"].ToString();
                driver.STATUS = myDb2DataReader["STATUS"].ToString();
                driver.REMAINING_HOURS = Convert.ToDouble(myDb2DataReader["REMAINING_HOURS"].ToString());
                driver.LAST_SAT_LOC = myDb2DataReader["LAST_SAT_LOC"].ToString();
                driver.LAST_SAT_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(myDb2DataReader["LAST_SAT_DATE"].ToString());
                result.Add(driver);

            }
        }
        myDb2DataReader.Close();
        myDB2Command.Dispose();
        myDb2Connection.Close();
        ViewBag.Drivers = result;

        return View(ViewBag.Drivers);
    }
```

I cannot figure out the difference in the environments that makes this query work and return the appropriate data on my machine but fails to return anything when deployed. If anyone has any answers for me it'd be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the database or hostname, or user-account, different between your development-PC and the deployed environment?   You can prove this by running the query from the db2cmd.exe command line after connecting to the database with the same account used by the application.  The most likely reason you get no rows is that no rows exist , that is assuming that you are catching all exceptions properly.

Comment: There is no differences between them, I have used to same query to directly pull from the database without issue - getting the data I desired. The same with my application when debugging, it retrieves the data fine. There shouldn't be any differences in environment because the 'deployed' environment for testing purposes is still my own machine just hosted on IIS.

Comment: Have you run the query at the db2cmd.exe command line, using same userid, database, schema as inside the code?